# Apple maps shows "directions not available" when launched from react-native app

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-maps

I building a react-native app in which i have used map to show certain locations. I have marked pins for each location on map. Now i want that if user select a marker and click on navigation button(which i have provided on map) it should launch apple map(for ios) and google maps(for android) and show navigation from user's current location to the latitude and longitude that i have passed in the map url.

But on apple maps it always show "direction not available" message.

Here is how i call map url for navigation:

```js
Platform.select({
      ios: () => {
             Linking.openURL('http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr='+latitude+','+longitude+'&dirflg=d&t=m');
          
      },
      android: () => {
          Linking.openURL('http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=' +latitude+ ',' +longitude);
      }
  })();
```

[image]

Can anyone please help me out here..

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently directions feature is not available in India because of this map is not showing you directions. You have to use Google Map.

For more clarification follow this link

https://www.apple.com/in/ios/feature-availability/#maps-directions

This link shows which feature is available in which country.

Comment: How we can make the directions available on our country too ? (In Azerbaijan for example)

Comment: You can use Google Map instead of Apple Map.

Comment: Apple removed it from apple store for Azerbaijan