# Can't show the directions in iPhone's inbuilt Map application

Tags: ios, swift, directions, apple-maps

This is my custom location set inside the iOS 10.0 iPhone 6 and iOS 11.2 iPhone 6 simulators.

[image]

And this is the code by which I am trying to open the iPhone's inbuilt Apple Map and show the directions from user's (above set) current location to the provided destination locations.

```
    let regionDistance: CLLocationDistance = 1000
    let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 26.025860999999999, longitude: 56.089238999999999)
    let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)
    let options = [MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
            MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span),
            MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving] as [String : Any]
    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = "Federal Electricity & Water Authority"
    mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)
```

but this is not working for at all. It's showing me the error like below,

[image]

Note:

1. I have given the location access permission to the default Map
   application.
2. All 4 `MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey` is not showing
   the direction.
3. Tested it on the Simulator and a real device and it is not working in either place.
4. Setting destination coordinates like this doesn't help. `let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 26.025861, longitude: 56.089239)`

Please help!

Comment: You will find answer on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47808584/apple-maps-shows-directions-not-available-when-launched-from-react-native-app/47808996#47808996

Comment: @Indrajeet, thank you for that link and your answer there, now I get to know that, the directions are only supported to the countries which are there on that list. So basically my location (UAE) is not there so it's not working for me. Thank you!

Comment: https://www.apple.com/in/ios/feature-availability/#maps-directions

Comment: @Hemang, Yes you can also find which feature is available for which region from this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Indrajeet commented, the directions in iPhone's Apple Map is limited to the countries which are listed in this [URL](https://www.apple.com/in/ios/feature-availability/#maps-directions).

So in my case, UAE is not listed currently.

Will update this answer in future once UAE will be listed.